# Using fopen in Raspberry pi4

Tags: python, c, fopen

In Raspberry Pi 4, I am trying to read a series of files(more than 1000 files) in the specific directory with the fopen function in the for loop, but fopen cannot read the file if it exceeds a certain number of iterations. How do I solve this?

Comment: What's your code like? If you are not closing the opened files then there's the possibility that your system is just running out of file pointers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], and how to [edit] your questions to improve it.

Comment: By the way, please don't spam with unrelated tag. Are you programming in C or Python?

Answer (score 1):

> but fopen cannot read the file if it exceeds a certain number of iterations.

A wild guess: you neglect to `fclose` the files after you are done with them, leading to eventual exhaustion of either memory or available file descriptors.

> How do I solve this?

Make sure to `fclose` your files.

Answer (score 0):

When you open file using `fopen` the system uses a file descriptor to point to that file. And there are only so many of them available. A quick  google search says microsoft usually has 512 file descriptors. Also, the file is loaded to memory. So, loading a lot of files will use up your memory fast. You should close each file after you are done with them. This usually is not a problem when working with a few files. But in case like yours where thousands of files are necessary, they should be closed as soon as possible after using them.